# Java 8 eagerly get the result of an intermediate stream operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given the following code:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        list.stream()
        .map(s -> s + "-" + s)                 //"a-a", "b-b", "c-c"
        .filter(s -> !s.equals("b-b"))         //"a-a", "c-c"
        .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

`map` and `filter` are intermediate operations and `forEach` is a terminal operation. Only after the execution of the terminal operation we can have the result of the data transformation.

Is there any way to *force* the evaluation to be more eager and to have some kind of *intermediate result* - without breaking the stream operations chain? For example I want to have the list of "a-a", "b-b", "c-c" (which would be the result of the first intermediate operation).

Comment: Can't you `peek` the stream between `map` and `filter`?        `map(...).peek(targetList::add).filter(...)`. Of course you need to use a thread-safe list if the stream is turn in parallel.

Comment: You can collect() them to a list or toArray them to an array, and then start a new pipeline.  Functionally, this does exactly what you want.  It isn't the *same* stream pipeline, but that is entirely an aesthetic objection.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
List<String> allPairs = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    list.stream()
    .map(s -> s + "-" + s)                 //"a-a", "b-b", "c-c"
    .peek(allPairs::add)
    .filter(s -> !s.equals("b-b"))         //"a-a", "c-c"
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

This way the computation still won't start until the terminal operation, but you can "intercept" the stream content at any point and use it in any way you like.

Beware however if your terminal operation is short-circuiting (like `findFirst`): this way not all the elements might be passed to `peek`.

Answer (score 7):

Well ... if I understand your question correctly, you have to apply a terminal operation, before filtering by the `not equals "b-b"` predicate. Then, you should call `.stream()` on the *intermediate* result and do the filtering:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
list.stream()
    .map(s -> s + "-" + s)           //"a-a", "b-b", "c-c"
    .collect(Collectors.toList())    //intermediate result
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.equals("b-b"))   //"a-a", "c-c"
    .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Comment: well it is kind of in the right direction but I would like to have the intermediate result assigned to something. Maybe the best approach is to use an intermediate `collect` with my own `Collector` implementation

Comment: Yes, I was just going to suggest that. Custom Collector is your friend. :)

Answer (score 0):

As Anton and kocko already stated, you can add your own collector, or use the Stream.collect method with the supplier, accumulator and combiner params:

```
    List<String> intermediateList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    list.stream().map(s -> s + "-" + s) // "a-a", "b-b", "c-c"
            .collect(() -> intermediateList, // supplier returns your intermediateList
                    (l, x) -> l.add(x), // accumulator - adds the element to your list
                    (l1, l2) -> {} // l1 and l2 are the same list, i guess - nothing to combine
            ) 
            .stream().filter(s -> !s.equals("b-b")) // "a-a", "c-c"
            .forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```