# Match string statement from with the elements of of string list and return index

Tags: java-8

In Java, I have a list of Strings that I want to match with a String statement. and whatever fits the string must obtain the index/(additionally add some number to the index) of that. What is the best way to accomplish this with Java 8?
For eg:

```
List tobeMatched = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("History","Geography"));
String sentence1 = "Chapter History is a boring one";
```

if **sentence1** contains history then return index of history +7 i.e : 14
if **sentence1** contains Geography then return index of history +9;

Two things I want to implement:

1. To check if the **sentence1**  matches any elements from **tobeMatched** .
2. If it matches then return the index Of the matched element from **tobeMatched**

`sentence1` contains `History`  is `true` also return index of **History** +length of history(matched element)  = 14.

In Normal way I can do it as :

```
int index = 0;
for(String match : tobeMatched)
{
 if(sentence1.contains(match ))
    index = sentence1.indexOf(match)+match.length();
}
return index;
```

I want to do it Java 8.

Comment: Please include the actual output string you want to see here.

Comment: What is your expected result if both the string present in the sentence1 ?

Comment: Looks like that was the reason you downvoted. I would have covered that scenario if that was a valid one on my case. That’s not allowed in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that

> I want to do it Java 8.

means that you want to use [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html).

Using streams does not automatically make your code better. As the saying goes: *the right tool for the right job* and in my opinion streams is not the right tool for the job that you want to do.

Having said that, the below code achieves your goal though not purely via streams since, as I already said, streams is not suitable for your task and your current code is probably the best way to do it.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.OptionalInt;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
    private static int index;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> tobeMatched = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("History","Geography"));
        String sentence1 = "Chapter History is a boring one";
        OptionalInt result = IntStream.range(0, tobeMatched.size())
                                      .filter(i -> {
                                          index = sentence1.indexOf(tobeMatched.get(i));
                                          return index >= 0;
                                       })
                                      .findFirst();
        System.out.println(index + tobeMatched.get(result.getAsInt()).length());
    }
}
```

Running the above code prints 15.

If `sentence1` does not contain a word from `tobeMatched` then the last line of the above code throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException`

As you can see from the above code, getting [intermediate results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231816/java-8-eagerly-get-the-result-of-an-intermediate-stream-operation) is not simple when using streams, hence my previous statement that streams is probably not the best way to achieve your task.

Comment: Yeah makes sense! +1  for the effort